# SDL window not showing?

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I have this simple code for SDL.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2_image/SDL_image.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0){
    return 1;
}

SDL_Window * win = SDL_CreateWindow("Window", 0, 0, 1920, 1080, SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN_DESKTOP);

if(win == nullptr){
    return 1;
}


SDL_Quit();
return 0;
}
```

None of this shows a window, I have error checked everything. It was working previously, but now it just opens and closes. I'm running on Xcode, if that helps.

Comment: Well, yes.  You're calling SDL_Quit immediately and you don't have a main loop.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't even appear with a main loop.

Comment: @anoyd_bi_me_grammers So if you plop a `while(true){}` right above `SDL_Quat()` It doesn't show the window?

Comment: while(true){} doesn't work sometimes for some reason, but I got the window to appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like the others state, your program terminates immediately so the window should "flash" momentarily. You can have the window appear for a few seconds by using [`SDL_Delay`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Delay):

```
SDL_Window *win = SDL_CreateWindow("Hello World!", 100, 100, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
if (win == nullptr){
    std::cout << "SDL_CreateWindow Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    SDL_Quit();
    return 1;
}

SDL_Delay(2000);

SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
SDL_Quit();
```

And remember to call [`SDL_DestroyWindow`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_DestroyWindow).

---

A `while(true) {}` loop will just cause your program to freeze. You probably want something like the following so that it listens for events, and you can close the window at your leisure.

```
SDL_Event e;
bool quit = false;
while (!quit){
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&e)){
        if (e.type == SDL_QUIT){
            quit = true;
        }
        if (e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN){
            quit = true;
        }
        if (e.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN){
            quit = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but why does while(true){} not work sometimes, I place it before SDL_Quit().

Comment: Thank you! No more unresponsive and disappearing windows!